# react-native missing navigation on react natvigation

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

i use react `native 0.66.0` and react `navigation 4.4.4` when run the app with yarn android got the error:

> undefined is not an object navigation.state.params.name

adding the file on `mainActivity.java` like document
it's my `App.js` file i have just one file on my app
[image]

[image]

Comment: when i change my react native to `0.63.0` is run

Comment: ops i missed up does not work!!!!!!!!